# What are some highlevel techniques to improving paint or rendering times?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

What are some techniques or methods that could potentially reduce jank and/or improve paint times on browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an exact answer for this but here are some high level techniques that may work for most situations

- Reduce paint layers - Use the browser's dev tools to see how many layers your css or markup may produce. Changing or simplifying your css could potentially reduce better outcomes
- Frame Budget - If the JavaScript inside your requestAnimationFrame callback takes longer than 16ms to run, you don't have any hope of producing a frame in time for v-sync
- Utlize a virtual dom, or Web Workers API - If possible offload processing away from the client and  Utilize web workers api for processing

Sources:

- [Jank Busting](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/rendering/)
- [Gone in 60 Frames Per Second](https://vimeo.com/75540354)